# How do I handle an Exception from an anonymous Task?

Tags: c#, exception, task, blockingcollection

I have a method that pulls data from a server in chunks and returns it for processing.  I made some measurements and found that it is significantly faster to download chunks in the background and return them via a `BlockingCollection<T>`.  This allows the client and the server to work at the same time rather than waiting on one another.

```
public static IEnumerable<DataRecord> GetData(String serverAddress, Int64 dataID)
{
    BlockingCollection<DataRecord> records = new BlockingCollection<DataRecord>();

    Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            Boolean isMoreData = false;
            do
            {
                // make server request and process response
                // this block can throw

                records.Add(response.record);
                isMoreData = response.IsMoreData;
            }
            while (isMoreData);

            records.CompleteAdding();
        });

    return records.GetConsumingEnumerable();
}
```

The caller (a C++/CLI library) should know that an exception occurred so it can try again or bail out as appropriate.  What's the best way to propagate the exception to the caller while minimally changing the return type?

Comment: Have you considered Task Factory and Task Continuation Options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why fire-and-forget tasks are generally a bad idea. They're even worse of an idea in your case since you're not wrapping your adding inside a `try/catch` with `records.CompleteAdding` inside the `finally` block meaning that the call to `MoveNext` on the enumerator from your `GetConsumingEnumerable` will eventually block indefinitely - that's bad bad bad.

If you were operating entirely within the bounds of C#, the solution would be simple: better separation of concerns. You strip out the `BlockingCollection` bit and run it where it belongs: in the consumer (client), or the intermediate pipelined processing stage (that's ultimately what you're trying to achieve) which will be designed in a way that it remains aware of any of the exceptions thrown by the producer. Your `GetData` signature then remains the same, but it becomes a simple blocking enumerable with full exception propagation:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataRecord> GetData(String serverAddress, Int64 dataID)
{
    Boolean isMoreData = false;
    do
    {
        // make server request and process response
        // this block can throw

        yield return response.record;
        isMoreData = response.IsMoreData;
    }
    while (isMoreData);
}
```

Then the pipeline looks like this:

```
var records = new BlockingCollection<DataRecord>();

var producer = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var record in GetData("http://foo.com/Service", 22))
        {
            // Hand over the record to the
            // consumer and continue enumerating.
            records.Add(record);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // This needs to be called even in
        // exceptional scenarios so that the
        // consumer task does not block
        // indefinitely on the call to MoveNext.
        records.CompleteAdding();
    }
});

var consumer = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var record in records.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // Do something with the record yielded by GetData.
        // This runs in parallel with the producer,
        // So you get concurrent download and processing
        // with a safe handover via the BlockingCollection.
    }
});

await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer);
```

Now you can have your cake and eat it too: the processing happens in parallel as the records are yielded by `GetData`, and `await`ing the producer task propagates any exceptions, whereas calling `CompleteAdding` inside the `finally` ensures that your consumer does not get stuck in a blocking state indefinitely.

Since you're working with C++ the above is still applicable to an extent (that is, the right thing to do would be to reimplement the pipeline in C++), but the implementation may not be so pretty, and the way you've gone with ,your answer may very well be the preferred solution even if it does feel like a hack due to the unobserved task. I can't really think of a scenario where it would *actually* go wrong since `CompleteAdding` always gets called due to the newly introduced `try/catch`.

Obviously another solution would be to move the processing code to your C# project, which this may or may not be possible depending on your architecture.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  I wish I could use the C# pipeline you suggest, but I need to transform each `DataRecord` into a corresponding C++ type and pass them up through many layers of MFC nastiness.  My solution is indeed cleaner in this situation, but I will most likely use this pattern at some point in a pure C# project.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I've found is to return a `DataResult` context, which may contain an exception after its records have been enumerated.

```
public class DataResult
{
    internal DataResult(IEnumerable<DataRecord> records)
    {
        Records = records;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataRecord> Records { get; private set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; internal set; }
}

public static DataResult GetData(String serverAddress, Int64 dataID)
{
    BlockingCollection<DataRecord> records = new BlockingCollection<DataRecord>();
    DataResult result = new DataResult(records.GetConsumingEnumerable());

    Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            try
            {
                Boolean isMoreData = false;
                do
                {
                    // make server request and process response
                    // this block can throw

                    records.Add(response.record);
                    isMoreData = response.IsMoreData;
                }
                while (isMoreData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Exception = ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                records.CompleteAdding();
            }
        });

    return result;
}
```

If there was an exception, the caller (C++/CLI) can rethrow it.

```
void Caller()
{
    DataResult^ result = GetData("http://foo.com/Service", 22);

    foreach (DataRecord record in result->Records)
    {
        // process records
    }

    Exception^ ex = result->Exception;
    if (ex != nullptr)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```